# How to create regular time intervals on GPS data for a Hidden Markov Model

Tags: r, time, gps, spatial, hidden-markov-models

I want to apply a hidden Markov model to some tracking data I have. I have read that the data need to be sampled at a regular time interval for this model to work. However, my tracks aren't always exactly regular. How do I regularise my dataset in R?

Here's some mock data as an example for you to work with

```
tracks <- read.table(text = 
                   "latitude,  longitude time
                 52.111122,  -10.544271  12:00
                 52.10944,   -10.554933  13:00
                 52.108898,  -10.558025  14:00
                 52.108871,  -10.560946  15:01
                 52.113991,  -10.582005  16:22
                 52.157223,  -10.626506  17:00
                 52.194977,  -10.652878  18:04
                 52.240215,  -10.678817  19:09
                 52.26421,   -10.720366  20:00
                 52.264015,  -10.720642  21:05"
                 , header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `approx` you can interpolate the positions to regular intervals:

First, change the time to POSIXct:

```
tracks$time <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s %s", Sys.Date(), tracks$time))
tracks$type = "original"
```

Calculate intervals:

```
n <- nrow(tracks)
tracks2 <- data.frame(
  latitude = approx(x = tracks$time, y = tracks$latitude, n = n)$y,
  longitude = approx(x = tracks$time, y = tracks$longitude, n = n)$y,
  time = as.POSIXct(approx(tracks$time, 1:nrow(tracks), n = n)$x, origin = "1970-01-01"),
  type = "corrected"
)
```

You can inspect changes in positions with a ggplot:

```
ggplot(rbind(tracks, tracks2), aes(x = time, y = latitude, color = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = tracks2$time, minor_breaks = NULL, labels = format(tracks2$time, format = "%H:%M") ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any best practice for this? For instance, should I interpolate at a coarser temporal resolution than my original data are sampled at?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. However, you can try with different resolutions. Note that I updated the sample to allow for `n > nrow(tracks)`. Try with different values of `n`.